# HTML E-Mail Loading Methodology - Inquiry

Tags: html, email, loading, footprint

This may be a stupid question, but How do HTML emails load in the message viewer? Is it synchronously or asynchronously? Does it depend on the platform? I would like to experiment with getting load time information via email footprints. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> How do HTML emails load in the message viewer?

However the e-mail client chooses to load them.

> Is it synchronously or asynchronously?

Not at all sure what you mean by this... the e-mail client can do whatever it wants with the HTML.  Some e-mail clients will load any external resources before the user even opens the e-mail.

> Does it depend on the platform?

Yes.

> I would like to experiment with getting load time information via email footprints.

If you intend to track load time anywhere outside of the e-mail client code itself, this is impossible.  It also isn't all that relevant.  Again, e-mail clients can and do pre-fetch resources.  Some services like Gmail proxy all the external resources.